# Why does the Uniqueness Principle imply real identities are true in the complex analogue?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

**Uniqueness principle theorem** :If $f$ and $g$ are analytic functions on a domain $D$, and if $f(z)=g(z)$ for $z$ belonging to a set that has a non isolated point, then $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in D$.

Why does this show all identities with entire functions holds true for those of complex functions? I guess I don't understand the phrase "belonging to a set that has a non isolated point." The definition for isolated point is given by:

**Isolated Point** : We say $z_0 \in E$ is an isolated point of the set $E$ if the is a $\rho>0$ such that $|z-z_0|\ge \rho$ $\forall z \in E$ other than $z_0$.

Edit: For example, since $\cos(z)$ and $\sin(z)$ are entire any identities with then such as $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ hold in the complex case.

Comment: No, isolated point doesn't mean that all other points are a positive distance from $z_0$.  It means that there's some positive distance $\rho$ such that ALL the points are at least a distance $\rho$ away from $z_0$.  To put it another way, it means the disc of radius. $\rho$ centered at $z_0$ doesn't constrain any of the points, except for $z_0$.

Comment: I cannot understand your question, do you know the proof for this fact? Note that a domain is connected (otherwise the equality does not hold), therefore you just have to prove that the set of zeroes of a holomorphic function is clopen (just use the power series expansion to the "open" part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the two functions $f(z) = \sin(2z)$ and $g(x) = 2\sin(z)\cos(z)$.  These two entire functions agree on the real line. So by the identity property, they are equal everywhere.  Does this make more sense?